# Show that $T:\,c_0\to c_0\;\;$, $x\mapsto T(x)=(1,x_1,x_2,\cdots),$ is non-expansive

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed linear space and $X=c_0$ (the space of sequences of real numbers which converge to $0$). Define 
\begin{align} T:\,&c_0\to c_0  \\ &x\mapsto T(x)=(1,x_1,x_2,\cdots), \end{align}
for arbitrary $x=(1,x_1,x_2,\cdots)\in c_0.$ I want to show that $T$ is non-expansive.

**Remark:** We have that

$$c_0=\{\bar{x}=(x_1,x_2,\cdots) :x_n\to 0\;\text{as}\;n\to \infty\}.$$

**MY TRIAL**

Let $x,y\in c_0.$ WTS: there exists $0\leq k\leq 1,$ such that $\Vert T(x)-T(y) \Vert \leq k \Vert x-y \Vert . $

Now,
\begin{align} \Vert T(x)-T(y) \Vert &=\Vert (1,x_1,x_2,\cdots)-(1,y_1,y_2,\cdots) \Vert\\&=\Vert ( 0,x_i-y_i)\Vert\\&= \sup\limits_{i\in \Bbb{N}} \{0,|x_i-y_i|\}\\&= \sup\limits_{i\in \Bbb{N}} \{|x_i-y_i|\}\\&=\Vert x-y \Vert \end{align}
Taking $k=1,$ (based on mathworker21's advice and BigbearZzz's help), then

\begin{align} \Vert T(x)-T(y) \Vert \leq k \Vert x-y \Vert . \end{align}
I'll be interested to see if you have a different kind of proof.

Comment: in your 'WTS', it's equivalent to take $k=1$. also do you know what the norm $||\cdot||$ is here? this problem is pretty trivial

Comment: Yes, your proof is correct.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: Thank you very much Sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've computed that
$$\begin{align}
||Tx-Ty|| &= \sup \{0,|x_1-y_1|,|x_2-y_2|,\dots\},
\end{align}$$
whereas we know that 
$$
||x-y|| =  \sup \{|x_1-y_1|,|x_2-y_2|,\dots\}.
$$
All you need to know to solve the problem is that norm for $c_0$ is the supremum norm.

Comment: Do we need to have $\sup?$, seeing that $c_0=\{\bar{x}=(x_1,x_2,\cdots) :x_n\to 0\;\text{as}\;n\to \infty\}.$

Comment: @Mike It's the standard norm on $c_0$ that makes it a Banach space. I think this should be written in your book/problem sheet.

Comment: The norm on $c_0$ is defined to be $||x|| =  \sup_{i\in\Bbb N} |x_i|$.

Comment: Maybe I'll get top know that as time goes on! I'm teaching myself Functional analysis with the help of a book. Anyway, is my proof correct?

Comment: Thanks about the norm info. That is an addition. Thanks!

Comment: As I mentioned above, your proof is basically complete except for the fact that you haven't written down explicitly the norm of $c_0$.

Comment: Okay, I'll write it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Kindly check now if it's totally fine!

Comment: Looks good now :)

Comment: Thanks! I acknowledged you above! Bye!