# Show that $T:\,c_0\to c_0\;\;$, $x\mapsto T(x)=(1,x_1,x_2,\cdots),$ has no fixed points

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

As a follow-up to my previous question [Show that $T:\,c_0\to c_0\;\;$, $x\mapsto T(x)=(1,x_1,x_2,\cdots),$ is non-expansive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3039099/show-that-t-c-0-to-c-0-x-mapsto-tx-1-x-1-x-2-cdots-is-non-expan).  Let $X$ be a normed linear space and $X=c_0$ (the space of sequences of real numbers which converge to $0$). Define 
\begin{align} T:\,&c_0\to c_0  \\ &x\mapsto T(x)=(1,x_1,x_2,\cdots), \end{align}
for arbitrary $x=(1,x_1,x_2,\cdots)\in c_0.$ I want to show that $T$ has no fixed points.

**Remark:** We have that

$$c_0=\{\bar{x}=(x_1,x_2,\cdots) :x_n\to 0\;\text{as}\;n\to \infty\}.$$

**MY TRIAL**

Suppose for contradiction that $T$ has fixed points in $X$, then there exists $u\in c_0$ s.t. $T(u)=u.$ That is, 
\begin{align}  T(u_1,u_2,\cdots)=(u_1,u_2,\cdots), \end{align}
Please, how do I draw out a contradiction from this?

Comment: which book of this question can you suggest me..please

Comment: @Inverse Problem: I got this from my the book "C.E. Chidume, Applicable Functional Analysis, Ibadan University Press Publishing House, 2014, University of Ibadan, Ibadan, Nigeria. ISBN: 978-978-8456-31-5". There are several other books too!

Comment: ........can you tell me...https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3159556/diameters-distances-and-contraction-mappings-on-a-subset-of-c-mathbbr0-1/3160690?noredirect=1#comment6508592_3160690 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3160256/a-question-about-fixed-points-and-non-expansive-map/3160356?noredirect=1#comment6508522_3160356   which have this questions? do you have idea

Comment: Applicable Functional Analysis  u have this book?

Comment: @Inverse Problem: Yes, I do!

Comment: @Inverse Problem: It contains part of the problem.

Comment: ..do you have pdf can u send me

Comment: @Inverse Problem: Yes, I do but as you know, it's against the Copyright laws. The Author is my Supervisor. He can be contacted before that is done. You can email me at momojola@aust.edu.ng

Comment: i sent mail to you ..or if u can u send me to suresh2maths@gmail.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(1,u_1,u_2,...)=(u_1,u_2,..)$ implies $1=u_1,u_1=u_2$ etc so $u_n=1$ for all $n$. But then $(u_n) \notin c_0$.

Comment: Sorry Sir, how's $u_n\notin c_0$?

Comment: Let me guess, it's because $u_n$ does not go to zero and $n\to\infty.$ Therefore, $u_n\notin c_o. $ I'm I right?

Comment: Yes, $u_n \to 1$.